# UsedRange loop bigger than anticipated

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table with 22 rows where I want to go through column B only. My loop goes beyond the 22 rows and reaches 259 for some reason.

Code

```
Debug.Print "Starting..."
Dim tempRange As Range
Set tempRange = Sheet18.UsedRange.Columns("B")

Dim i As Integer
i = 0
For Each Cell In tempRange.Cells
    i = i + 1
Next Cell
Debug.Print "Count: " & i
```

Intermediate Window

```
Starting...
Count: 259
```

Screenshot showing Sheet18 with 22 rows

[image: Table with 22 rows]

Screenshot showing table reference with 22 rows

[image: Table reference showing 22 rows]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`UsedRange` has issues, as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba).

Since you have a table, or `ListObject`, just iterate through the cells in the `ListColumn`.

```
Dim myTbl as ListObject
Set myTbl = Sheet18.ListObjects("Table24")

Dim rng as Range
For Each rng in myTbl.ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange
    ...
Next rng
```